# Creating checkout sessions at store level

Tags: magento

I'm trying to create different checkout sessions for the logged in customer at a store level, rather than at the site level.

We have a site with 2 stores. When a user adds a product to the cart, we want to show that product in the cart only for that store. But currently switching between stores will show up products of other stores previously added to the cart.

After some research I found that whenever a user logs in to a store, a record is created in the `sales_flat_quote` table for the logged in customer, which is common for all the stores in that site. So I need to create a new record in the `sales_flat_quote` table when the user switches stores.

I found that the `loadByCustomerId()` function in class `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote` is what creates the new record in the `sales_flat_quote table`. But all I see is a select query:

```
$read = $this->_getReadAdapter();
$select = $this->_getLoadSelect('customer_id', $customerId, $quote)
                ->where('is_active=1')
                ->order('updated_at desc')
                ->limit(1);
$data = $read->fetchRow($select);
```

I don't understand how the select query is creating the record in the `sales_flat_quote` table.

Could someone guide as to how to create a new record in this table for the logged in customer when he/she switches to an other store under the same site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have a site with 2 stores. When a user adds a product to the cart,
>   we want to show that product in the cart only for that store. But
>   currently switching between stores will show up products of other
>   stores previously added to the cart.

Which is **correct**.

It looks like you want to separate carts for `store` definitions, which both are connected to the very same `website` definition in Magento.

In Magento, all `store`s defined within the same `website` do always **share** the very same cart.

That's *by-design*.

To achieve cart separation you would need to change your Magento setup to have *two* `website`s and *one* `store` per website. Otherwise you'll run into endless issues separating the two stores (like the issue you're having now), I guess.

That said, I'll nevertheless try to answer your concrete question:

> I don't understand how the select query is creating the record in the
>   `sales_flat_quote` table.

A `SELECT` query usually never ever will *create* a record; it's thought to *read* data.

Have a look at `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::loadCustomerQuote()`:

```
$customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId());
```

This is what leads to the call of `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote::loadByCustomerId()` you're talking about. It just *loads* the customers quote (if any), nothing else.

Creation/update of the record happens by calling the quotes **`save()`** method.

Magento EE 1.11.0.0 for example saves the record this way:

```
if ($customerQuote->getId() && $this->getQuoteId() != $customerQuote->getId()) {
    if ($this->getQuoteId()) {
        $customerQuote->merge($this->getQuote())
            ->collectTotals()
            ->save();   // <- either this 
    }

    $this->setQuoteId($customerQuote->getId());

    if ($this->_quote) {
        $this->_quote->delete();
    }
    $this->_quote = $customerQuote;
} else {
    $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
    $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    $this->getQuote()->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer())
        ->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();   // <- or that does the save
}
```

You didn't mention the Magento version you use, so your mileage may vary, but the principle will still remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for trying to clear things for me.I am working on Magento 1.5.1. I found the code you mentioned in the session model. Trying to debug the code, i see that when ever a user logs in, if there isn't a record existing for that user in the `sales_flat_quote` table, a new record is created. This is happening even before the save() method. I confirmed this by placing a die right after `$customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId());` and the new record is created.

Comment: I guess i will go with separate sites-> stores setup. We have about 10,000 customers, so the idea was to separate out the carts at store level while sharing the same customer data across both the stores. Thanks for trying to help me Jurgen.

Comment: @Nithin: I might be wrong (never have had a setup sharing customers, but separating carts yet), but afaik each `website` has its own, separate customer base, so I'm afraid Magento won't let you share customers across two `website`s. At least not by default. I'd recommend to test that first, to make sure it doesn't shape up as a dead end.

Comment: I have been trying to get this working for a few days now. Maybe i'll get back to it later, but for now i think i will go with the separate site rout. Thanks anyways.